# How to stop FilterMessage to proceed further?

Tags: wpf, textbox, message, handle, intptr

I am looking forward to find a way to stop my message to proceed further or in other words to make it handled.

Say, cursor location is at textbox and I am scanning a barcode "#Save#". I recognized using WindowProc that this is barcode text and I handled Save text (by saving my form) but now I don't want to write this text("#Save#") in textbox.

So in short sentence I am looking for property or method to say a window this text (input) is handled, don't do any further action.

```
HwndSource source = (HwndSource)PresentationSource.FromDependencyObject(this);
source.AddHook(WindowProc);

private IntPtr WindowProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)

{  

    if(device == barcode)  
    {  
        ......
        .....
        //Did some action

        //tried to stop msg to follow further in loop, but not working
        handled ==true;
    }

return IntPtr.Zero;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that a typo, extra equals sign? Your code reads:

```
handled ==true;
```

that's not an assignment, although, I don't think that should even compile...

```
did you mean:

handled = true;
```